# Overlapping List for ios in xamarin

Tags: ios, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am making a demo project. I have implemented listview in xamarin view and binding data from API. In first place it looks proper but as I scroll the list starts getting overlap and gets more overlap as I am scrolling to the end point of screen. I have tried with various solutions but did not get solution. It will be great if anyone can help me out with it.
this is my code

```
 <ListView  x:Name="UserListView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="True" RowHeight="100" IsVisible="true"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ScrollView>
                                <StackLayout>

                                    <Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="0" HeightRequest="100" HasShadow="False">
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="15,15,15,15" >
                                            <Image Source="image.png" />
                                            <Label Text="{Binding id}" TextColor="Black" />
                                            <Label Text="{Binding title}" TextColor="Black" />
                                            <Label Text="{Binding userId}" TextColor="Black" />
                                            <Label Text="{Binding completed}" TextColor="Black" />
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </Frame>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ScrollView>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: Why you put `ScrollView` inside item template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                           <StackLayout>
                                    <Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="0"  CornerRadius="0" Margin="0,-5,0,0" HeightRequest="100" HasShadow="False" BorderColor="Black">
                                        <Frame IsClippedToBounds="True" VerticalOptions="Center" CornerRadius="0" Margin="0,-10,0,0" BackgroundColor="White" Padding="0" HeightRequest="90">
                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="15,15,15,15" >
                                                <Image Source="image.png" />
                                                <Label Text="{Binding id}" TextColor="Black" />
                                                <Label Text="{Binding title}" TextColor="Black" />
                                                <Label Text="{Binding userId}" TextColor="Black" />
                                                <Label Text="{Binding completed}" TextColor="Black" />
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </Frame>
                                    </Frame>
                                </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
```

Worked for me by adding a frame inside a frame and make it IsClippedToBounds ="True".
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Greate, remember to mark the answer when you have time.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms permits `ListView` cell **reuse** through the [ListViewCachingStrategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listviewcachingstrategy) enumeration, which has the following values:

```
public enum ListViewCachingStrategy
{
    RetainElement,   // the default value
    RecycleElement,
    RecycleElementAndDataTemplate
}
```

The **RecycleElement** caching strategy specifies that the `ListView` will attempt to minimize its memory footprint and execution speed by recycling list cells.

Here you need to use `CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"` could solve this problem.

As follows:

```
<ListView  x:Name="UserListView" 
           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
           HasUnevenRows="True" 
           RowHeight="100" 
           IsVisible="true"  
           VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" 
           CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
       ...         
</ListView>
```